# Value (CRC-16 X 25) to HDLC frame

Tags: java, crc16

I have an example frame:

`7E FF 10 9A 45 F2 7B F1 00 0A CF 7E`

`0A CF` --> is a CRC-16 X.25 value from these bytes: `FF 10 9A 45 F2 7B F1 00`

Do you know of an example algorithm for this CRC calculation in Java?

Comment: (Be eprecise: *0A CF* (*not* `OA`) and (most probably) [*X.25*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.25).) What have you tried in Java? Where do you see yourself stuck? `I use this website` Did you inspect the ECMAScript code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try some code before posting a question.

Comment: I have posted CRC-16 Java code here, including the X.25 constants.

Comment: (EJP posted it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A207421+CRC-16+Java+X.25).)

Comment: You need to attempt the conversion yourself first, and if it doesn't work, _then_ post a question here with your attempt, what went wrong, and asking for help. Despite EJP's answer (and some of mine as well), this is not a site to get people to search for or write code for you for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent project I added an implementation of the CRC-16/X-25 calculation.

I posted it there: https://github.com/mdeverdelhan/Topaz512-driver/blob/v1.0.0/src/main/java/eu/verdelhan/topaz512/Crc16.java#L35 (it is called CRC-B).